# Can't get the navbar to be smaller in height using padding

Tags: html, css, user-experience

I want to accomplish two things:

1) Fix the navbar thickeness so its 8px padding above and below. Right now it looks like its 20-30px. The navbar should be 100% wide with the navbar menu to be 960px centered.

2) Left align the website title and right align the menu links on the same row.

http://jsfiddle.net/5rp5B/

HTML

```
<header>

  <div class="nav_top_bar">
    <nav class="nav_top_menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="nav_top_title">Web Site Title</li>
        <li><a href="" class="blue">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="green">Products</a></li>  
        <li><a href="" class="orange">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="purple">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="yellow">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.nav_top_bar {
  background-color: #333333;
  padding: 8px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav_top_menu {
color: #c3c3c3;
font-size: 1em;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
width: 960px;
}

.nav_top_title {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.nav_top_menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav_top_menu ul li {
  display: inline;
}

.nav_top_menu ul li a {
  color: #c3c3c3;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
```

Comment: There are no borders declared in your CSS.

Comment: Sorry, I meant fix the height of the navbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra padding is due to the fact that most browsers add margins and padding to the `ul` element.
You can explicitly set `margin: 0; padding: 0;` on the `ul` element to get rid of these.

You can also align the links (left and right) with floats and the `:first-child` selector.

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7w8CA/1/

Comment: That left/right aligns to full 100%. How do I accomplish this within the 960px centered while still giving the navbar full 100% width background color?

Comment: The menubar IS centered..but the contents are not. Try giving the menubar a different bg color to see.

Comment: @user1052448 Sorry, didn't see anything in the question about the 960px. I'll edit that in the Fiddle. Basically, you should use `max-width: 960px` instead of `width: 960px`.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that the top bar seems too big in height, try adding this to your styles to remove the default margin on the `<ul>` element:

```
.nav_top_menu ul {
  margin:0;
}
```

And for the title and links you can do this instead, which will align everything to the right except the title which will be floated to the left:

```
.nav_top_menu ul {
  margin: 0; 
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
}
.nav_top_menu ul li {
  display: inline;
}
.nav_top_menu ul li.nav_top_title {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

And yeah make sure to remove the default margin from the `<body>` element as well:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `body` and `ul` are assigned default margins/padding bu the browser so these should be reset.

**[**JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rp5B/16/)****

**CSS**

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav_top_bar {
  background-color: #333333;
}

.nav_top_menu {
color: #c3c3c3;
font-size: 1em;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 960px;
padding: 0;
}

.nav_top_title {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.nav_top_menu ul {
  list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
        text-align: right;
}

.nav_top_menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav_top_menu ul li:first-of-type {
  float:left;
      padding: 8px 16px;
}

.nav_top_menu ul li a {
  color: #c3c3c3;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the following addition in the CSS rule:

Add padding/margin values to the `.nav_top_menu ul` class.

```
.nav_top_menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
```

To align the way you want, first make all `li` text aligned right, then left-align the first-child element:

```
.nav_top_menu ul li { text-align: right}
.nav_top_menu ul li:first-child { text-align: left }
```